# Making table cells tappable in tabular adaptive card

Tags: typescript, adaptive-cards

I have a tabular adaptive card with two columns, of which I need to make each table cell in the first column tappable. The use case is: There is a list of names in a database which are retrieved and displayed in the first column of the tabular adaptive card if specific condition is satisfied. The next thing to perform is for each name in this column, if the name is clicked it will display some contact information related to the name. How can this be achieved  using typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the above problem I was basically trying to make the `TextBlock` tappable. As there is no `selectAction` property for the `TextBlock`, the solution is: to wrap the `TextBlock` which has to be made tappable inside a `Container` and then add the `selectAction` property on the `Container`.

This works fine. However, it would be great if the `selectAction` property is available for the `TextBlock` too, which would prevent adding the extra layer of `Container` for each `TextBlock` that has to be made tappable.

Any other solutions are welcomed!